# lower_bound() algorithm/STL usage preconditions

Tags: c++, linux, stl, c++17, stl-algorithm

The code below returns erroneous results if compiled for 32bit Linux systems, and the same problem applies to 64bit systems, given large enough vectors.

Have the preconditions of lower_bound or STL in general been violated, and if so, where?

I have been informed by STL sources that the size of the vector is cast to a signed type, which explains the behaviour.

```
// compile with and without -m32 switch
#include<algorithm>
#include<iostream>
#include<stdexcept>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int main() {
 try {
  vector<uint8_t> v((1ULL << 28) * 9, 2); // 2.25 G entries
  v.back() = 3;                           // the last of which is greater
  cout<< "Vector maximal size: "<<v.max_size()<< " and actual size: " << v.size() <<endl;
  uint8_t val=3;
  auto x= lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), val );
  if (x!=v.end() && !( val< *x ) ) {
   cout << "Found value " << int(*x) << endl;
  } else {
   cout << "Not Found " << endl;
  }
 } catch (exception const & ex){
  cerr<< ex.what()<<endl;
 }
}
```

Output: (Linux OS & Clang++ 7.0.0)

```
Vector maximal size: 4294967295 and actual size: 2415919104
Found value 2
```

Output: (Windows 10 OS & 32bit-msvc)

```
vector<T> too long
```

---

Update: While a fix for std::vector is under way, the problem persists for arrays allocated by

```
auto p= new uint8_t[sz]; // 2.25 G entries
```

and the result depends on compiler & stdlib.

Comment: Is `v.size() > v.max_size()` in your compilation?

Comment: No, Linux max_size()=4G  is too large and Microsoft STL is right. Does it throw bad_alloc?

Comment: It throws `std::length_error` ([vector.capacity], `reserve()`: Throws: `length_error` if `n > max_size()`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In libstdc++ the function `lower_bound(...)` uses `distance(...)`, it starts with:

```
typedef typename iterator_traits<_ForwardIterator>::difference_type  _DistanceType;
_DistanceType __len = std::distance(__first, __last);
...
```

According to the Standard (23.2, [container.requirements]):

> Expression: `a.max_size()`; return type: `size_type`; operational semantics: `distance(begin(), end())` for the largest possible container

`distance(...)` returns `difference_type` (24.4.4, [iterator.operations]]

> ```
> template<class InputIterator>
> typename iterator_traits<InputIterator>::difference_type
> distance(InputIterator first, InputIterator last);
> ```

Hence, `max_size()` should return a value than can be represented using a signed type (`int32_t` in the present case). However, `max_size()` returns `4'294'967'295`. I guess this is a bug in libstdc++.

By the way, in Microsoft STL implementation `max_size()` returns `2'147'483'647`.